# C# Making a picturebox always move

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a picturebox in my Form and i want to move,always,from the start of the program,how can i do it?I only want this:

```
pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X + 1, pictureBox2.Location.Y - 1);
```

Thanks

Comment: when you want to move it? when the program start? and keep moving after? then you need to create a timer and put your piece of code inside the Tick(or Elapsed) event

Comment: Are you saying you want it to be in a different location than it was in the designer when you start the program, or are you saying you want it to move around the screen continuously while the program runs?